# Why does this mean $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is closed?

Tags: general-topology

Statement: Let $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ be the countably infinite product of $\mathbb{R}$ with itself, and let $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ be the subset of $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ consisting of all sequences that have only finitely many nonzero elements. Then, in the box topology, $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is closed.

I have found a proof of such a fact, but I am having trouble understanding how we can draw the conclusion in the last step.

Proof: Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^{\omega} - \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$. Then, $x$ has only finitely many elements equal to zero. A neighbourhood of this sequence $x$ is given by $U = U_1 \times U_2 \times \ldots$, where $U_k = \mathbb{R}$ if $x_k = 0$ and $U_k = (0,2x_k)$ is $x_k > 0$ or $U_k = (2x_k,0)$ if $x_k < 0$. Then, $U$ contains no elements of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$, **and $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is closed.**

I have bolded the part which I do not understand why it is true. If anyone can explain it to me, that would be a great help.

Comment: One comment with this attempted proof: It's not clear to me an element of $\Bbb{R}^{\omega}-\Bbb{R}^{\infty}$ has finitely zero values. Unless I'm missing something, the only think we can say about an element $x\in \Bbb{R}^{\omega}-\Bbb{R}^{\infty}$ is that it has infinite nonzero values. (like, say, $x_{2k}=0, x_{2k + 1}=1$)

Comment: @NateRiver. Right. The first assertion of the proof is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is closed, it suffices to show the complement is open. They do so by showing that for any point in the complement, there is an open neighborhood of the point contained entirely in the complement.

Comment: Showing that every point in a set is contained in an open neighbourhood which is also in that set proves the set itself is open?

Comment: @Sorey Yes, since then the set can be written as the union of all these open neighborhoods, and thus is open.

Comment: @sorey It might help to do the topology of $\mathbb{R^n}$ first before going into general topology. Just going by your comment above it suggests you may have not. A lot of real analysis on $\mathbb{R^n}$ is what ultimately motivates these definitions in general topology.

Comment: @DavidReed, I appreciate your concern. Believe me, I am trying. I am taking my first ever course in topology this semester, and I am working on problems in my sparetime with the section we are currently covering in class. My professor started from the basics but he is RACING through material at an unbelievable pace (started with defining topology, and we are starting quotient topologies next lecture, the 5th lecture of the semester). I am trying my best to keep up but having a very hard time remembering all the different results that go together in this field. Thanks for your advice, though.

Comment: @Sorey Ah ok. I just mentioned that because when one initially does real analysis on $\mathbb{R}^n$ one defines an open set to be one in which you can put an open ball around any point and stay in that set. Then once you've done the topology on $R^n$ you effectively have know the basics of topology on any metric space. Makes the transition smoother. Good luck though! I think you'll find this site is an amazing resource. I certainly have.